# How to Automate tasks in R

Tags: r

I would like to find a way to automate descriptive statistics in R.
I always have to repeat the same steps for every csv file I import. 
While I'd rather have a way to truly automate this. Right now I do:

```
myvariable <-read.csv(file="my.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
names(myvariable)
```

Check which columns I want to look at in names:

```
x <- myvariable$ColumnName
plot(x) (in various plot types)
```

What I would like to do is:

Read in one (maybe all) csv files in a folder and assign the different columns to variables (or maybe a data frame, I don't know which is best). These variables than should be useable in different plots (e.g. boxplot, density etc), without me having to change the whole script again when I change the csv I want to import.

I hope that my question makes sense. I would like to have a way where I can put csv files in a directory, run the script and the see basic descriptive statistics results plotted.

Thank you !

Comment: `plot(myvariable$ColumnName)` works just fine. There is no reason to assign to a variable. How to import all files in a folder and loop over them has been shown often on SO.

Comment: Indeed. Just use `for (file in list.files(folder)) { if(grepl("csv$", file)) { ... } }`

Comment: @faidherbard Have a look at the `pattern` parameter of `list.files`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a functional programming problem. Basically, just write a function that inputs a dataset and variable name (or whatever inputs you need for your statistical method) and then outputs the result of the method or the plot. Here's a hacky little toy example:

```
library(ggplot2) #for diamonds dataset
sum_plot <- function(data, var1, var2){
  print(var1)
  print(summary(data[ ,var1]))
  print(var2)
  print(summary(data[ ,var2]))
  plot(data[, var1], data[, var2])
}

sum_plot(mtcars, "cyl", "mpg")
sum_plot(diamonds, "carat", "cut")
```

This is a super powerful way of thinking about R code. Highly recommend this chapter on the subject. 
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html